# Hibernate use property fields of an object in formula annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I am fairly new to hibernate, and I am running into an issue that I am trying to overcome with very basic code just to get it to the point of working.  Here is what I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="budgetfunds")
public class BudgetItem implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="budgetFundsID")
    private int budgetFundID;

    @Column(name="budgetYear")
    private int budgetYear;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "semesterID")
    private Semester semester;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fundCategoryID")
    private FundCategory fundCategory;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "fundCategoryID", referencedColumnName = "fundCategoryID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "semesterID", referencedColumnName = "semesterID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "year", referencedColumnName = "budgetYear")
    })
    private Set<Fund> fundItems;

    @Column(name="budgetID")
    private int budgetID;

    @Column(name="budgetFundAmount")
    private BigDecimal fundAmount;

    @Formula(value = "select sum(f.fundAmount) from Fund f where f.fundCategoryID = fundCategoryID and f.semesterID = semesterID and f.year = budgetYear")
    private BigDecimal requestedAmount;

    ...
}
```

Here is my problem.  I have a set of fundItems that I need to sum and set as this object's property so that it can be referenced in jsp. The last property is my attempt to do that... the only problem is, it is not valid sql because it doesn't know where the semesterID, budgetYear, and fundCategoryID values are coming from. Is there a way to fix this query to work **per object**?

Also, if there is an easier way to do this without completely refactoring code/database let me know.

Here is a diagram of the database and relations:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching all over the place, I finally found someone's tutorial about hibernate using "derived properties".
Here is the source:

http://blog.eyallupu.com/2009/07/hibernate-derived-properties.html

And here is the specific solution to my issue:

```
@Formula(value = "(select sum(f.fundAmount) from Fund f " + 
    "where f.fundCategoryID = fundCategoryID " +
    "and f.semesterID = semesterID "+
    "and f.year = budgetYear)")
private BigDecimal requestedAmount;
```

To explain how this works, I will quote a section from the link above:

> ...by not declaring an alias on a column (the [fundCategoryID, semesterID, and budgetYear] columns in here), I can reference the ***owning entity*** columns - this is usually required when my formula needs to fetch associated entities...

Comment: Thanks for sharing, plus one. Will update my answer after some testing.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I might cause unnecessary confusion. The mistake was the query was using `budgetFundID` instead of `budgetFundsID` . You can try the update one here -`@Formula(value = "(select sum(f.fundAmount) from Fund f where 
    f.fundCategoryID = (select b.fundCategoryID from BudgetFunds b where b.budgetFundsID = budgetFundsID) 
    and f.semesterID = (select c.semesterID  from BudgetFunds c where c.budgetFundsID = budgetFundsID)
     and f.year = budgetYear)")` and this should help as well. Although I prefer your approach. Would be interested to know if this is working as well.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu I don't really have a way of testing it now because we made some changes to the layout of the database that would cause the query to no longer work. Ultimately I ended up joining to another table to get the semesterID, fundCategoryID, and year values and use the ID of the entries that match those fields to return the fundAmount

Comment: No problem. In case you ever get to test it any time, would be interested to know the outcome.